# How can I apply border to the top of each row in grid display?

Tags: css

How can I apply border to the top of each row in grid display?
Something like this, but in one container. I try to search this problem in Google, but did not find something like this.

```css
.container {
  max-width: 700px;
}
.tab {
  border-top: 1px solid #000;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
        grid-gap: 5px;
        
}

.tab2 {
  border-top: 1px solid #000;
  padding-top: 10px;
  display: grid;
         
}

.item {
  width: 150px;
  height: 70px;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="tab">
    <div class="item">1</div>
    <div class="item">2</div>
    <div class="item">3</div>
  </div>
  <div class="tab2">
    <div class="item">4</div>
  </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: In one container I mean one div with class tab in this example

Comment: @Kirlll, are you looking for something like this - https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/wYpQKw

Comment: No, I am looking for border in top of each row, when you apply display: grid to div.tab

Comment: I mean that if item 4 was in div.tab but border still the same

Answer (score 0):

To achieve expected reult , use width: fit-content on tab2

```css
.container {
  max-width: 700px;
}
.tab {
  border-top: 1px solid #000;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 5px;
        
}

.tab2 {
  border-top: 1px solid #000;
  padding-top: 10px;
  display: grid;
  width: fit-content;          
}

.item {
  width: 150px;
  height: 70px;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="tab">
    <div class="item">1</div>
    <div class="item">2</div>
    <div class="item">3</div>
  </div>
  <div class="tab2">
    <div class="item">4</div>
  </div>
    </div>
```

codepen - https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/zmpMdR